# SQL GROUP_CONCAT split in different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I searched a lot, but didn't find a proper solution to my problem.

What do I want to do?

I have 2 tables in MySQL:
- Country
- Currency
(I join them together via CountryCurrency --> due to many to many relationship)

See this for a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/317d3/8/0

I want to link both tables together using a join, but I want to show just one row per country (some countries have multiple currencies, so that was the first problem).

I found the group_concat function:

```
SELECT country.Name, country.ISOCode_2, group_concat(currency.name) AS currency
FROM country
INNER JOIN countryCurrency ON country.country_id = countryCurrency.country_id
INNER JOIN currency ON currency.currency_id = countryCurrency.currency_id
GROUP BY country.name
```

This has the following result:

```
NAME            ISOCODE_2   CURRENCY

Afghanistan AF          Afghani
Åland Islands   AX          Euro
Albania         AL          Lek
Algeria         DZ          Algerian Dinar
American Samoa  AS          US Dollar,Kwanza,East Caribbean Dollar
```

But what I want now is to split the currencies in different columns (currency 1, currency 2, ...). I already tried functions like MAKE_SET() but this doesn't work.

Comment: SQL does not support a dynamic number of columns. You will have to do it in the application.

Comment: You could use logic in a Cursor to do this.  But the cursor would first have to look into how many columns of data your result set needed.  The dynamically create a temp table to be populated and later selected.  A dynaminc number of columns is the issue with this challenge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `substring_index()`.  The following query uses yours as a subquery and then applies this logic:

```
select Name, ISOCode_2,
       substring_index(currencies, ',', 1) as Currency1,
       (case when numc >= 2 then substring_index(substring_index(currencies, ',', 2), ',', -1) end) as Currency2,
       (case when numc >= 3 then substring_index(substring_index(currencies, ',', 3), ',', -1) end)  as Currency3,
       (case when numc >= 4 then substring_index(substring_index(currencies, ',', 4), ',', -1) end)  as Currency4,
       (case when numc >= 5 then substring_index(substring_index(currencies, ',', 5), ',', -1) end)  as Currency5,
       (case when numc >= 6 then substring_index(substring_index(currencies, ',', 6), ',', -1) end)  as Currency6,
       (case when numc >= 7 then substring_index(substring_index(currencies, ',', 7), ',', -1) end)  as Currency7,
       (case when numc >= 8 then substring_index(substring_index(currencies, ',', 8), ',', -1) end)  as Currency8
from (SELECT country.Name, country.ISOCode_2, group_concat(currency.name) AS currencies,
             count(*) as numc
      FROM country
      INNER JOIN countryCurrency ON country.country_id = countryCurrency.country_id
      INNER JOIN currency ON currency.currency_id = countryCurrency.currency_id
      GROUP BY country.name
     ) t
```

The expression `substring_index(currencies, ',' 2)` takes the list in currencies up to the second one.  For American Somoa, that would be `'US Dollar,Kwanza'`.  The next call with `-1` as the argument takes the last element of the list, which would be `'Kwanza'`, which is the second element of `currencies`.

Also note that SQL queries return a well-defined set of columns.  A query cannot have a variable number of columns (unless you are using dynamic SQL through a `prepare` statement).

Comment: @Luv . . . My apologies.  I didn't see the SQLFiddle link in the question.  The above code is tested and works.

Comment: Perfect it works! Thanks for the quick and very correct answer! I'll accept it as an answer is some as the time limit is over :p

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to work out the number of currency columns you'll need:

```
SELECT MAX(c) FROM 
((SELECT count(currency.name) AS c
FROM country
INNER JOIN countryCurrency ON country.country_id = countryCurrency.country_id
INNER JOIN currency ON currency.currency_id = countryCurrency.currency_id
GROUP BY country.name) as t)
```

Then dynamically create and execute [prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23178848/495157) to generate the result, using Gordon Linoff solution with query result above to in this thread.

Answer (score -2):

Ypu can use dynamic SQL, but you will have to use procedure