# How to Create dynamic query in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing an Oracle ADF web application using jDeveloper. For that am using

- jDeveloper
- MySql database
- Integrated WebLogic (which came with jDeveloper)

So am trying to **Create a Query-only Business Service Based on Parameters**. For this I need to create a query which will take values at run time.

I am following a tutorial in that they gave(because tutorial followed oracle) oracle equivalent query

```
select first_name,last_name from employees where email=:p_mail
```

But I need mysql query equivalent to the above (because I am following MySql DB).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178816/mysql-dynamic-query-in-stored-procedure might help.

Comment: the above link talking about stored procedure. But am not dealing with stored procedure. In orcale ADF app am creating Business service Based on parameters. Whenever I entered into a window the above query I am getting the following error

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':p_email' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Same as Oracle your query will be :

```
$show_list = $bdd->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees WHERE email = :p_mail");
$show_list->execute(Array(':p_mail' => $user_email));
$show_list->fetchAll();
```