# Delete between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to delete between tables?

Something like...

```
delete from bd between table1 and table 10 where vehicle 761 

delete from bd.table_1 where id_vehicle=761
delete from bd.table_10 where id_vehicle=761
```

Comment: A `DELETE` statement does only delete from one table. (With foreign keys, and triggers, you can have data deleted from several tables.)

Comment: How is `between table1 and table 10` supposed to act?

Comment: Yes, I'm with andy, is it suppose to delete from table1 table2 table3...table10?

Comment: I'm doing this manually:

delete from bd_veosat_posiciones.ruta_2016_01_26 where id_vehiculo=761;

delete from bd_veosat_posiciones.ruta_2016_01_25 where id_vehiculo=761;

delete from bd_veosat_posiciones.ruta_2016_01_24 where id_vehiculo=761;

delete from bd_veosat_posiciones.ruta_2016_01_23 where id_vehiculo=761;
I'm curious if exist a sentence to do this without a for or  while to incremetent the day.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a stored procedure (look at [mysql dynamic query in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178816/mysql-dynamic-query-in-stored-procedure))
or change the table structure so that either the vehicle IDs are related via a foreign key constraint (then you can do cascading deletes, see http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade), or use one big table to store everything, but partition it by date, if the content really reaches a size, where it makes sense.