# Sqoop Import replace special characters of mysql

Tags: mysql, hive, special-characters, sqoop

I have 1000 tables with more than 100000 records in each table in mysql. The tables have 300-500 columns.

Some of tables have columns with special characters like .(dot) and space in the column names.

Now I want to do sqoop import and create a hive table in HDFS in a single shot query like below

```
sqoop import --connect ${domain}:${port}/$(database) --username ${username} --password ${password}\
--table $(table) -m 1 --hive-import --hive-database ${hivedatabase} --hive-table $(table) --create-hive-table\
--target-dir  /user/hive/warehouse/${hivedatabase}.db/$(table)
```

After this the hive table is created but when I query the table it shows error as

This error output is a sample output.

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field emp from [0:emp.id, 1:emp.name, 2:emp.salary, 3:emp.dno]
```

How can we replace the .(dot) with _(underscore) while doing sqoop import itself. I would like to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sqoop import \ with  **--query**  option rather than --table and in query use [replace](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php) function .

ie

sqoop import --connect ${domain}:${port}/$(database) --username ${username} --password ${password}\
-- query 'Select col1 ,replace(col2 ,'.','_') as col from table.

**Or (not recommended)** write a shell script which can do find and replace "." to "_" (Grep command)at  /user/hive/warehouse/${hivedatabase}.db/$(table)

Comment: I tried the --Query Option but to replace in many column names using select query is where I am stuck

Comment: Please excuse me for asking too may questions I am a bit new to Hadoop How do I write a dynamic query

Comment: using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS you can get column name and column datatype and biased on  column datatype for 'char','varchar' use Repace function .      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names ....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178816/mysql-dynamic-query-in-stored-procedure