# Remove Spaces/Special Characters in Column Name while sqoop from Teradata to cloudera hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, cloudera, sqoop

i'm able to sqoop the Teradata table into Hive Cloudera sucessfully, But Teradata table has column name with Space and special characters like "Material ID", "Active/InActive" like this, but in hive this not standard and facing lot of issues while querying.

How to remove spaces and special characters in column name while inserting?

i'm using below sqoop command,

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:teradata://ABCD/database=db1,logmech=LDAP" \
--username **** \
--password **** \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \ 
--hive-database abc_stg \ 
--hive-table product_dim \
--query "select * from product_dim where \$CONDITIONS" \
--target-dir /dev/edl/md/addy/str/abc_stg/product_dim \
--fields-terminated-by '|' -m 1 --delete-target-dir
```

Comment: FYI In Teradata the object name qualifiers are `"` (e.g.`"Material ID"`). In Hive its `\`` (e.g. `\`Material ID\``)

Comment: If it aren't too many columns you can use `select column_name as simple_name,... from product_dim where ...`. This will solve your issue but not in a very clean way.

Comment: @spijs, columns are many and I need to do it for Manu tables

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz, thanks for your comment, we don't have any way so I can remove space in column names

Comment: @HaneepCR - I didn't understand

Comment: @HaneepCR What you still could do is create a script which will read all column names, replace the special characters and then modify and run a sqoop command containing `column_name as simple_name` for all columns. It is a workaround but it should work and scale.

Comment: @spijs, Thanks will try out..

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, Sqoop has any inbuild function which removes space and special character in column names while creating table in hive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902381/sqoop-import-replace-special-characters-of-mysql