# Is it possible to write a variable after SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

It is necessary to write a procedure that makes a request, which, in turn, should output all the objects of a particular column.
Here is what I tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AttributeRequest(n CHAR(200))
begin
  SELECT n FROM table;
end
```

But this variable is perceived as the name of the column itself and nothing comes out.
Tell me how to make such a request by the attribute of the object, please

I searched a bit, read the answers below, and I managed to implement this task in the following way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AttributeRequest(n CHAR(200))
begin
    SET @t =CONCAT("SELECT ",n ," FROM table");
    PREPARE e FROM @t;
    EXECUTE e;
end
```

Comment: You can write the dynamic query as an option see below link which might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178816/mysql-dynamic-query-in-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to use dynamic sql for this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AttributeRequest(@n CHAR(200)) AS
begin
  declare @query varchar(1000);
  set @query = 'select ['+@n+'] FROM table;
  exec AttributeRequest @query
end
```

then you can excute it ,

```
exec AttributeRequest 'columnname'
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but I was unable to start your piece of code.