# Pivoting query based on dynamic columns data using MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

have one table called A and the data is like below:

```
TaskId  Activity TestData
111     ACT1     X
111     ACT2     Y
111     ACT3     Z
```

have one more table called B and data like below:

```
Activity   Comments
ACT1       CM1
ACT2       CM2
ACT3       CM3
```

need the result to be displayed like below , in which comments column is dynamic data.

```
TaskId  ACT1  Comments  ACT2   Comments  ACT3   Comments
111     X     CM1       Y      CM2       Z      CM3
```

Comment: MySQL is really bad at doing that. You should do that in your program logic if possible.

Comment: As mentioned, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

This is SQL pivoting query:

```
SELECT
    TaskId,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(A.Activity='ACT1', TestData, null)) ACT1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(A.Activity='ACT1', Comments, null)) Comments1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(A.Activity='ACT2', TestData, null)) ACT2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(A.Activity='ACT2', Comments, null)) Comments2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(A.Activity='ACT3', TestData, null)) ACT3,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(A.Activity='ACT3', Comments, null)) Comments3
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.Activity = B.Activity
GROUP BY TaskId
;
```

Looks [SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=800b32dc0350f0ce0cf4be75afd5e96d&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: please can you help me out in above query, how to pass the dynamic values for Activity and comments. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dynamic queries available in stored procedures. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178816/mysql-dynamic-query-in-stored-procedure

Comment: please help me, I want to pass comma separated values for ID to fetch data using while loop and combine all the table result which i am getting from while loop result inner join with main table and get it all in one table data. thanks in advance

Comment: SQL not suitable for implement so complicated logic. Do it in your application layer.