# Pass column name dynamically for joining table in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

For the last few days, I have been working to write a MySQL query to extract a result. Basically, I have to join two tables `log` and `conditions` table based on any column of the `log` table from the `trigger_param_value` column. Here the column name of `log` table is present in the `trigger_param_name` column of the `condition` table.

I have already write a SQL query.

```sql
 select al.* from log as al
 inner join conditions as hc on hc.action=al.action 
   and al.<hc.trigger_param_name> = hc.trigger_param_value
 where al.date_time >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
  AND al.date_time < CURRENT_DATE and customer_id is not null
  group by al.customer_id;
```

The problem is occurring for the second condition of the inner joining `al.<hc.trigger_param_name>= hc.trigger_param_value`. `<hc.trigger_param_name>`contains the column name of the column name of the log table.

**Note: The `trigger_param_name` column contains different different column name based on row.**

How can I dynamically set the column name?

Comment: Please add table definitions, sample data and expected outcome as text...I suspect your approach is flawed and the db design is flawed.

Comment: Thank you for your effort.  It is working fine although I have not provided the DB definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You will need to write out the separate join criteria for each of the columns:

```sql
SELECT al.*
FROM log AS al
INNER JOIN conditions AS hc
    ON hc.action = al.action
    AND (
        (hc.trigger_param_name = 'col1' AND al.col1 = hc.trigger_param_value) OR
        (hc.trigger_param_name = 'col2' AND al.col2 = hc.trigger_param_value) OR
        ...
    )
WHERE al.date_time >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
AND al.date_time < CURRENT_DATE
AND customer_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY al.customer_id;
```

This query should lead to a 1055 error, as `customer_id` is not a unique key within the `log` table. Without knowing the structure of the tables and expected outcome, it is not possible to suggest how this should be fixed.

Please read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) for more details on the importance of [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) and writing deterministic queries.

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot dynamically set the column name*, but there are other ways to achieve what you want. One i can suggest is using **case statement**.

```
select al.* from log as al
inner join conditions as hc 
    on hc.action=al.action 
    and case hc.trigger_param_name
        when 'column1' then al.column1
        when 'column2' then al.column2
        # more column goes here
    end = hc.trigger_param_value
where al.date_time >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
AND al.date_time < CURRENT_DATE and customer_id is not null
group by al.customer_id;
```

I should mention while you cannot dynamically set the column name as filter, you can [make entire query dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178816/mysql-dynamic-query-in-stored-procedure) for your reference. But for your case, query above i provided should be enough.